# Polar growth property for harmonic Maass forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, harmonic-functions

The definition of a harmonic Maass form consists of three properties; (1) that it is modular, (2) that it is harmonic, and (3) that it has at most polar growth at the cusps (ordered in accordance with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_Maass_form). I was wondering whether the property (3) is implied by the other properties. Is there an example of a modular harmonic function on the upper half plane that grows super-exponentially towards infinity?

Comment: If $j(z)$ is the $j$-invariant, then $e^{j(z)}$ would be an example of a function that satisfies (1) and (2) (with weight $0$) but not (3).